# Stop duplicates appearing when listing songs by artist or album in Grooveshark

Tags: grooveshark

I prefer to listen to entire albums or all songs from a single artist at a time, but the huge number of duplicates that appear when listing songs from a single album or artist makes this a very painful experience right now as I have to manually pick out the songs one by one or remove the duplicates after adding them to the playlist.

[image]

Is there an option in Grooveshark itself to only show one version of each song when listing them?

Comment: related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/how-do-i-avoid-playing-duplicate-songs-on-grooveshark

Answer (score 2):

As stated by phwd in the other question:

You will need [Grooveshark Enhancement Suite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nbglmejghppifhhbdhbaijiagbaedeec?hl=en-US) but it will only remove songs to the best of its ability. Users who name the song incorrectly are not detected.

Before:

[image: Before extension]

Click remove duplicates in the bottom right hand corner.

[image: Remove duplicates]

After removing *exact* duplicates

[image: Duplicates removed]

In the above it was only able to remove one exact duplicate.