# How do I avoid playing duplicate songs on Grooveshark?

Tags: grooveshark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop duplicates appearing when listing songs by artist or album in Grooveshark](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10736/stop-duplicates-appearing-when-listing-songs-by-artist-or-album-in-grooveshark)

For example - what if I want to play the top rated songs of a particular artist (such as http://grooveshark.com/#!/artist/Jupiter+Rising/48483), and want to quickly remove all the repeated instances of their "Electropop" song?

As usual, I have limited time and I don't want to manually remove them.

Answer (score 3):

You will need [Grooveshark Enhancement Suite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nbglmejghppifhhbdhbaijiagbaedeec?hl=en-US) but it will only remove songs to the best of its ability. Users who name the song incorrectly are not detected.

Before:

[image: Before extension]

Click remove duplicates in the bottom right hand corner.

[image: Remove duplicates]

After removing *exact* duplicates

[image: Duplicates removed]

In the above it was only able to remove one exact duplicate.